# Não consigo clicar no link do menu

Tags: css, html5

No menu lateral eu não estou conseguindo clicar nele, já fiz de tudo porem nada da certo HELP...

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
.imagemMenu{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
}
ul{
    top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
nav{
    background-color: rgba(16, 16, 16, .5);
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    left: -250px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ nav{
    transform: translateX(250px);

}
.Amenu{
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.Amenu:hover{
    background-color: rgb(176,224,230);
}
label{
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.Hunters{
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-top: 1.1%;
    position: absolute;
}
.animation-area{
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #303030, #000000e7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.box-area{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.box-area li{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);
    animation: animete 20s linear infinite;
    bottom: -150px;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(1){
    left: 86%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(2){
    left: 12%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation-duration: 7s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(3){
    left:  70%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    animation-delay: 5.5s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(4){
    left:  42%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 15s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(5){
    left:  65%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(6){
    left:  15%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(7){
    left:  30%;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(8){
    left:  79%;
    width: 90px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(9){
    left:  95%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
}

@keyframes animete{
    0%{
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(-800px) rotate(360deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hunters Developers</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body class="body-page">
    <div class="topo">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chec">
        <div class="cab">
            <label for="chec">
                <img class="imagemMenu" src="img/206-2069918_menu-icon-png-menu-icon-white-png.png">
            </label>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="Amenu" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="Amenu" href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
                <li><a class="Amenu" href="MeusTrabalhos.html">Trabalhos</a></li>
                <li><a class="Amenu" href="contato.html">Contrate</a></li>
                <li><a class="Amenu" href="Mensagem.html">Enviar mensagem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <h3 class="Hunters">Hunters Developers</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="animation-area">
        <ul class="box-area">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não consegue porque o menu está por baixo da div onde possui essa animação, que é a `div.animation-area`, que possui um `z-index` de `9999`, ficando por cima de tudo.

Você vai resolver alterando o `z-index` para `-1` e adicionando a propriedade `position: relative`, pois o `z-index` só funciona em elementos com `position`, `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed` ou `sticky`.

Veja:

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
.imagemMenu{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
}
ul{
    top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
nav{
    background-color: rgba(16, 16, 16, .5);
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    left: -250px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ nav{
    transform: translateX(250px);

}
.Amenu{
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.Amenu:hover{
    background-color: rgb(176,224,230);
}
label{
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.Hunters{
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-top: 1.1%;
    position: absolute;
}
.animation-area{
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #303030, #000000e7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
}
.box-area{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.box-area li{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);
    animation: animete 20s linear infinite;
    bottom: -150px;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(1){
    left: 86%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(2){
    left: 12%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation-duration: 7s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(3){
    left:  70%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    animation-delay: 5.5s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(4){
    left:  42%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 15s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(5){
    left:  65%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(6){
    left:  15%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(7){
    left:  30%;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(8){
    left:  79%;
    width: 90px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(9){
    left:  95%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
}

@keyframes animete{
    0%{
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(-800px) rotate(360deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hunters Developers</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body class="body-page">
    <div class="topo">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chec">
        <div class="cab">
            <label for="chec">
                <img class="imagemMenu" src="img/206-2069918_menu-icon-png-menu-icon-white-png.png">
            </label>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="Amenu" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="Amenu" href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
                <li><a class="Amenu" href="MeusTrabalhos.html">Trabalhos</a></li>
                <li><a class="Amenu" href="contato.html">Contrate</a></li>
                <li><a class="Amenu" href="Mensagem.html">Enviar mensagem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <h3 class="Hunters">Hunters Developers</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="animation-area">
        <ul class="box-area">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cara deu certo, muito obrigado!! me salvou

Comment: É só marcar a resposta com ✔.

Comment: tive um problema cara, quando eu coloco o z-index: -1; e o position: relative; realmente funciona eu consigo interagir com o menu porem quando dou f5 na pagina o site ja carrega meio bugado, sendo o bug : o background ta meio que partido em listras e o site assim que a pagina carrega fica uma tira branca bem no rodapé da pagina ai passa uns 10s a pagina vai subindo e volta ao normal sabe como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Coloca `display: flex;` no `.animation-area` e `align-self: stretch;` no `.box-area`.

Comment: não deu certo cara, cada hora que eu dou f5 a tira branca no rodapé da pagina é de um tamanho diferente, ai com um tempo por exemplo 10 seg eu vou rodando o scroll do mouse ela vai sumindo como se a pagina tivesse subido, tem como anexar uma imagem aqui :?? para eu te mostrar, sou novo aqui no stack. sem contar que o background ta todo listrado como se estivesse dividido